# Why does this php function loop endlessly?

Tags: php, recursion

Why can't I call this function with the function and increment it's argument?
It seems to loop endlessly without $i incrementing.

```
 function loopy($i) {
        loopy($i+1);
        echo $i.'...';
        if ($i >=5) return true; 
 }
```

Comment: 1. What are you trying to achieve. 2. why not use an actual loop?

Answer (score 2):

Because the if statement needs to go before calling the function again to stop it beign an infinite loop:

```
function loopy($i) {
        if ($i >=5) return true; 
        loopy($i+1);
        echo $i.'...';  
}
```